# org.hibernate.TransactionException: transaction timeout expired

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gradle, migration

I am getting while running all my test cases which is about 400. It is able to run for some tests but for 130 I am getting the error `org.hibernate.TransactionException: transaction timeout expired`, but when I run that specific test which has the same error then it passes. any suggestion would be welcome.

the error message is:

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: transaction timeout expired at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.determineRemainingTransactionTimeOutPeriod(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:271)

Comment: Is this question active? The answer was not accepted, no feedback.

Comment: If the test are run in the different test suits the all the tests are passing in jenkins but in ant project same test are passing without creating the test suits.

Comment: The issue was with the transaction management of beans. thanx